# How to wipe or erase data wearable by tizen ide?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am building a app which can erase data on wearable(2.x) with tizen ide?

How to do it?

I try to wipe data with "http://tizen.org/privilege/dpm.wipe" 
But API Privileges support on tizen 4.0.

Comment: Are you trying to delete files from Gear device? Would you please share in detail here?

Comment: Hi Shaswati Saha, I want to clear all data of wearable. Setting -> Gear info -> Reset Gear.

Answer (score -1):

I have answer.

-According to this link : **"https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https%3A//developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__DPM__SECURITY__POLICY__MODULE.html&langredirect=1#ga529f0da309999bc6f0ed3fd719f77602"**

The dpm_security_wipe_data() function can use to wipe data on Tizen 3.0.